# Function range problem

Tags: calculus, functions

$(sin^2\theta  +\sin\theta -1)/(sin^2\theta -\sin\theta+ 2)$ .
It is asked to find the range of this function.

Here i was assumed a variable 
$z=sin\theta$ so that i get

$-1<=z<=1 $

and then i obtained a quadratic equation as :-

$(y-1)z^2 -(y+1)z + 2y +1 =0$  from here i need some help or if there's some other way for this  problem that might also help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z^2 - z + 2 = (z - 1/2)^2 + 7/4$, the given function's domain is $\mathbb{R}$.

$$f(z) = \frac{z^2 + z - 1}{z^2 - z + 2} = 1 + \frac{2z- 3}{z^2 - z + 2}$$

Let us differentiate the function.

$$f'(z) = \frac{(2z - 3)' (z^2 - z + 2) - (2z - 3) (z^2 - z + 2)'}{(z^2 - z + 2)^2} \\= \frac{2z^2 - 2z + 4 - (2z - 3)(2z - 1)}{\text{A positive number}} = - \frac{2z^2 - 6z - 1}{\text{A positive number}}$$

What can you talk about the shape of $f(z)$? When $f(z)$ has local maximum/minimum?

Comment: Check the nominator of the last fraction, please.

Comment: Oops... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\frac{\sin^2 x+\sin x-1}{\sin^2 x-\sin x+2}$

Then $g(z):=f(\sin^{-1} z)=\frac{z^2+z-1}{z^2-z+2}$ $$g'(x)=\frac{(2x+1)(x^2-x+2)-(2x-1)(x^2+x-1)}{(x^2-x+2)^2}=\frac{-2x^2+6x+1}{(x^2-x+2)^2}$$

In order to find maxima and minima, set $g'(x)=0$: $-2x^2+6x+1=0$.  Thus $x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{11}}{2}$.  Note that $\frac{3+\sqrt{11}}{2}>1$ and is not an element of the domain.

You should be able to finish the thought process.